# Bootstrap 3 RC1: Column Ordering

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid-layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two primary boxes: an 8-col wide box with a bunch of panels and a second, 4-col (offset-1) to the right as a sidebar.

I want to push the sidebar on top of the box o' sidebars on small screens. I've tried applying `col-12 col-push-12` (panel box) and `col-12 col-pull-12` (sidebar box) without any luck. I also want to ensure the sidebar is "centered" (i.e. as if it was col-offset-4 col-4) on the grid when it's pushed up top as well.

I've also noticed some movement (open issues) on the Bootstrap repo over at GitHub regarding some of this behaviour, but I might just be conflating things.

```
<div class="container content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-12">
            <div class="panel listing">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-12">
            <div class="sidebar">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Above is the "vanilla" code as it stands right now: what do I need to do to get the sidebar above on mobile and tablet?

**Update**: It appears the accepted answer/implementation no longer works due to some commits (given that "RC1" isn't what I'd call an RC!) today: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commits/3.0.0-wip

If anyone has an updated answer I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the order of elements like that (there are no `push-12` or `pull-12` classes in Bootstrap) so you must change the order in your markup and use column ordering on large screens instead

```
<div class="container content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-push-8 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
            <div class="sidebar">
                SIDEBAR
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-pull-4 col-sm-12">
            <div class="panel listing">
                PANEL
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8bxYr/3/)**

Also I just found out that the Bootstrap 3 CSS file hosted at NetDNA is not up to date and doesn't have the push/pull classes well implemented, so I had to download the official file and copy the css code to the fiddle

Comment: — fantastic, thanks very much. Appreciate the clarification re: lack of `push-*` classes.

Comment: Note that this answer doesn't seem to work with the latest `HEAD` (par for the course with non-final release).